# Firestore security .data rule doesn't work

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a short question about Firestore security rules.

Let's say that I have a document "user" in my firestore database that contains "userID" field.

Now I want to write a security rule that allows user to delete this document only if their ID matches the "userID" field in the document they want to delete.

To do this I wrote the following rules:

```
match /users/{user} {
      ...
      allow delete: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.userID;
      ...
    }
```

And when I try to delete this document in the simulator, either if the rule should allow it (IDs match) or it shouldn't (IDs do not match) it gives me this error:

> Error running simulation — An unknown error occurred

What did i do wrong here?

Here's my document
[image]

Those are rules i set
[image]

And this is how i try to delete it

[image]

Comment: Hey Wikur, can you edit your question to include a screenshot of the document you're trying to delete and a screenshot of how you're deleting it from the simulator?

Comment: I agree with Frank, we need more details to help. The little bit of the rules you've included doesn't have any obvious syntax or structure mistakes.

Comment: I added those screenshots as you guys asked above

Comment: @WiktorLobejko Thanks for adding the photos, unfortunately I can't spot anything wrong... in fact, just to reassure myself that I wasn't missing something obvious I copied your database & rules structure and tested it myself - the rule works as intended in my project. I'm sorry to say that I have no idea :(